# ffmpeg.exe not found inside project directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, path, electron

I´m currently working on my first electron / react app, which makes use of ffmpeg. I do have a problem to link the .exe file correctly.

The prolem I´m facing is that I `ffmpeg.exe` is not found when trying to link it with a relative path inside my project directory. When using an absolute path it does work.

The exe files are in the sub-folder of the current directroy.

It does work when I´m using such path:

`'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\development\\ytDownloader\\app\\utils\\ffmpeg\\ffprobe.exe'`

But when trying it like this 
`.setFfmpegPath('.\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe')`

or

`'./ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'`

it does not working.

Additionally I would really like to avoid using `\\` in my project.

Does someone have an Idea what I´m doing wrong here?

I get this error message:

```
Error: spawn .\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error msg was added

Comment: What happen if you remove the .\in the begining of the folder?

Comment: I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently started learning nodejs as well, could you try the following maybe ...using the path module

```
    var fs = require('fs'); 
var path = require('path'); 
var ffmpegPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'ffmpeg', 'ffmpeg.exe');
```

Then the ffmpegPath variable will give you access to the path you want,

Or try using

```
.setFfmpegPath('../ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe').
```

Where the .. represents the current directory

Comment: @BayLife It may be helpful to other users that ever come across this page to know what the 'small modification' was.